# Are multiple actions in a single transaction guaranteed to happen sequentially?

Tags: transactions, action

Suppose I have a transaction with two actions, A and B, listed one after another.
Like this:

```
{
  <...>,
  "actions": [
    {
      "account": "my.token",
      "name": "action_a",
      <...>
    },
    {
      "account": "my.token",
      "name": "action_b",
      <...>
    }
  ]
}
```

Is it guaranteed that A happens before B?

Comment: For what it's worth, the actions did happen sequentially when I tried it, but if it is not guaranteed and just happened by a happy accident, this will turn out to be problematic.

Comment: If you push a transaction you need a action , than you call other actions inside the initial action. Can you tell me what your actions are doing, they are independent on each other as I think

Comment: @Nirdesh My example on the mainnet is a transfer of 10 wizards.one's wizards (table entries) between my two accounts via two actions each: https://eosflare.io/tx/0b272ac729ee30974c3e06f579ece64a3b2e1d3ab614954e2dee0618da8acfad. For each of the 10 wizards, the second action (`getfrombuff`) should have failed if the first one (`putinbuff`) did not complete before that. The readable code is here: https://github.com/LetItPlay/CryptoWizards-SmartContract/blob/445400d/wizContract.cpp#L242-L273, it may be outdated but I believe the updated version to have the same effect.

Comment: @Nirdesh Tx paste: https://pastebin.com/rhUHqpKp.